# element.click function doesn't seem to work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a web scraping Macro in MS Excel, but I can't seem to make it click the button element from the page I'm trying to scrape data from. Here's my code

```
Sub GetFromSite()
    Dim getIE As New InternetExplorer

    With getIE
        .Navigate "http://www.starbucks.ph/store-locator/search"
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Do While getIE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Dim s_box As Object
    Set s_box = getIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0

    While i < s_box.Length
        If s_box(i).Name = "searchField" Then
            s_box(i).Value = "44.701360   -63.678170"
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Wend

    Dim sGo As Object
    Set sGo = getIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("button")






    Dim J As Integer
    J = 0
    While J < sGo.Length
        If sGo(J).Name = "find" Then
            sGo(J).Focus
            sGo(J).Click
        End If

        J = J + 1
    Wend


    Set s_box = Nothing
    Set sGo = Nothing

    getIE.Quit
    Set getIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope you can help me with this. I can't progress if I can make it through this error.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the Error its giving you?

Comment: There's no error that pulls up. I just see that there are no search results since the IE window opens up every time I run the code, so I assumed that the click function doesn't work.

Comment: Step through your code with F8 and watch it do it's job line by line. You can better observe whether the click has any effect.

Comment: From my experience of VBA web scraping, sometimes I have had to loop through all the anchor elements `<a>` and find the button containing the desired text to click. Of course a direct ID can also be used where available.

Comment: I think I've tried going through name, type, class. All of which is a unique identifier pointing to the button I need. I'm gonna try the F8 probing, maybe I'll see what's wrong from there. Thanks for the tip!